# Rails: How to Eager Load with Left Join Table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently I have a controller query which fetches products & product updates as follows:

```
products = Product.left_outer_joins(:productupdates).select("products.*, count(productupdates.*) as update_count, max(productupdates.old_price) as highest_price").group(:id)
products = products.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

This query creates N+1 query but I can not put .include(:productsupdates) since I have a left out join as well.

If possible, can you please help me how to reduce N+1 queries?

**EDIT------------------------------
As per Vishal's suggestion; I have changed the controller query as follows,**

```
products = product.includes(:productupdates).select("products.*, count(productupdates.*) as productupdate_count, max(productupdates.old_price) as highest_price").group("productupdates.product_id")
products = products.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

Unfortunately, I receive the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "productupdates"
LINE 1: SELECT  products.*, count(productupdates.*) as productupdate_count, m...
                               ^
: SELECT  products.*, count(productupdates.*) as productupdate_count, max(productupdates.old_price) as highest_price FROM "products" WHERE "products"."isopen" = $1 AND (products.year > 2009) AND ("products"."make" IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY productupdates.product_id LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please advise how this is causing N+1 and how you think this will solve the issue. The only way I can see an N+1 situation here is if you are then calling productupdates on each product later. If this is the case then this will not solve the issue. Please advise so others can formulate appropriate responses*

For the time being I am going to assume that somewhere later in the code you are calling `productupdates` on the individual products. If this is the case then we can solve this without the aggregation as follows

```
@products = Product.eager_load(:productupdates)
```

Now when we loop the productupdates are already loaded so to get the count and the max we can do things like

```
@products.each do |p| 
  # COUNT 
  # (don't use the count method or it will execute a query )
  p.productupdates.size 
  # MAX old_price
  # older ruby versions use rails `try` instead 
  # e.g. p.productupdates.max_by(&:old_price).try(:old_price) || 0
  p.productupdates.max_by(&:old_price)&.old_price || 0
end
```

Using these methods will not execute additional queries since the productupdates are already loaded

**Side note:** The reason `includes` did not work for you is that `includes` will use 2 queries to retrieve the data (sudo outer join) unless one of the following conditions is met:

- The where clause uses a hash finder condition that references the association table (e.g. `where(productupdates: {old_price: 12})`)
- You include the `references` method (e.g. `Product.includes(:productupdates).references(:productupdates)`)

In both theses cases the table will be left joined. I chose to use eager load in this case as `includes` delegates to `eager_load` in the above cases anyway

Answer (score -1):

You can directly do `Product.includes(:productupdates)` this will query the database with left outer join as well as it will overcome the N+1 query problem.

So instead of `Product.left_outer_joins(:productupdates)` in your query use `Product.includes(:productupdates)`

after firing this query in the console you can see that `includes` fires left outer join query on the table

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please guide me how to select specific columns and calculations as in my original query? .select("products.*,  count(productupdates.*) as update_count, max(productupdates.old_price) as highest_price").group(:id)

Comment: you can use select same as you were using earlier just use Products.includes(:productupdates).select('products.*, productupdates.*').group('productupdates.id')

Comment: you can use select with includes same as joins

Comment: Vishal, I have tried your suggested solution unfortunately received the error.. (I edited question to highlight current status)